# How much memory can CreateFileMapping request?

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory

I want to use shared memory to transfer large images (10M or more) between two processes, but I can only request 4096 bytes of BUF_SIZE when requesting shared memory.beyond 4096 bytes, the program will crash.

Here is my code:

```
hMapFile = CreateFileMappingW(
             INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
             NULL,                    // default security
             PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
             0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
             BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)超过4096就不行了，不知道怎么解决
             szMapName);
```

My system is windos64, Use C++ in qt.anyone have the same problem as me?

I think I know why the program crashed. It's because there's something wrong with the code below.

```
hMapFile = CreateFileMappingW(
         INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
         NULL,                    // default security
         PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
         0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
         BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
         szMapName);                 // name of mapping object

if (hMapFile == NULL){
    qDebug() << (TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),GetLastError());
    return -1;
}
pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(
       hMapFile,   // handle to map object
       FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
       0,
       0,
       4097);//if this number > 4096, the program will stuck

if (pBuf == NULL){
    qDebug() << (TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
    GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You probably have to show more code. There is no `4096` byte limitation.

Comment: Did you check the value of the HANDLE returned? If it is a NULL pointer the request failed.

Comment: What is `szMapName`? The function accepts an `LPCWSTR` for that parameter, just confirming that's an actual name, not something else. Regardless, try and make a proper [MCVE] so we're not guessing at what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You called `CreateFileMappingW` with `BUF_SIZE` as the low order `DWORD` size (with the high order `DWORD` being `0`, so `BUF_SIZE` is the total number of bytes). That's the limit on what you can map later with `MapViewOfFile`. I'm guessing you defined `BUF_SIZE` as a constant 4096 somewhere, so that's the limit on what `MapViewOfFile` can map. Use a larger number for `CreateFileMappingW` and `MapViewOfFile` can increase to match.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I defined the BUF_SIZE as 300000. Is it true that as long as the last parameter of MapViewOfFile is smaller than the BUF_SIZE, the program will work normally?

Comment: @vindur: It should work just fine if the requested `MapViewOfFile` size is less than or equal to what you mapped with `CreateFileMapping`. That said, are you *sure* that's what `BUF_SIZE` is defined to? It's a *very* common name, and with `#define`s, it could easily have been redefined to something else.

Comment: @vindu: In general, the lower 32-bit value of MapOfView is lower than the lower 32 value of CreateFileMapping, and there will be no problem, however, depending on the operating system, it is recommended to set the value of the BUF_SIZE not to exceed the maximum recognized memory.

Comment: Thank you so much, but when I replace BUF_SIZE directly with a number, the problem remains. Once the MapViewOfFile size is more than 4096, the following statement such as print or cout will not be executed.

Comment: and it will return -1, GetLastError() is 0

Comment: The value you get from `GetLastError()` is meaningless. You are calling it too late. There must not be *any* code in between the time where you established that `GetLastError()` returns a meaningful value and the time you're actually calling `GetLastError()`.

Comment: thanks, I had no problem running it on other people's computers, and then I had no problem running it myself. I don't know why, haha.

Comment: The code is still wrong. `GetLastError()` doesn't return any meaningful value at the time you're calling it. If you wish to find out what's wrong when, (not if) things start failing again, you'll want to fix the code. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) explains how to use the API.